# Cross Domain Request from a SharePoint Hosted Add-in to a WCF RESTful service hosted by Provider hosted Azure WebApp

Tags: jsom

I am trying to perform a cross domain request from SharePoint hosted add-in to a wcf service in provider hosted add-in.

**I have a hybrid setup as below:**

- SharePoint Office 365 site online, Azure subscription & other
  required elements in Azure AD
- A SharePoint hosted Add-in with a custom action and custom page,
  deployed successfully.
- A provider hosted Add-in which has a wcf RESTfulservice, deployed and
  published    successfully. I see the correct response when requested
  through browser.

Scenario: On a button click from a SharePoint hosted Add-in page, I would like to perform a cross domain request to WCF service which is hosted in Provider hosted Add-in. So ideally I am trying to get information from host web & perform some updates. But to start off , there is only one operation contract returning a string.

Please find the sample JavaScript:

---

```
try {

   context = new SP.ClientContext(appWebUrl);

   var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appWebUrl);

   var localHostUrl = "http://amigosito365.azurewebsites.net/MyHybridService.svc/GetResponse";

   //var localHostUrl = appWebUrl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/title?@target='" +

   // hostWebUrl + "'";

   executor.executeAsync(

   {

      url: encodeURIComponent(localHostUrl),

      //url: localHostUrl,

      method: "GET",

      headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },

      success: onQuerySucceeded,

      error: onQueryFailed,

      DataType: "jsonp"

   });

}
```

Using the above code, If I try to get the web title using the URL: `//var localHostUrl = appWebUrl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/title?@target='" +`

// hostWebUrl + "'";

I get the response json as expected however when I try to communicate with the RESTful service the response is not as excepted. I do not get any specific error and I am able to get in to the success call back function. But the body of data object has a big chunk of html and does not indicate any error.

On the other hand when I access the RESTful service in a web browser, I am seeing the response as expected.

Any help in solving the above issue would be really appreciated.

Comment: this might be helpul for someone who got stuck with same issue: I have managed to fix the above with the help of technical support from MS. I had to use SP.WebRequestInfo() to set the webservice url & execute the request through web proxy. Please refer to links: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179895.aspx

http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/158120/cross-domain-get-request-with-sp-requestexecutor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using SP.WebRequestInfo() to set the webservice url & execute the request through web proxy fixed the issues.